# MYSQL Bulk insert if not exists update if exists

Tags: mysql, bulkinsert, on-duplicate-key

I am looking for something similar-

```
insert into table1(a, b, c)
select col1 as d, col2 as e, col3 as f from table2
on duplicate key update b = e, c = f;
```

NOTE - Here table1.a is unique Key.

I am getting error- **Unknown column name 'e'.**

Is there any solution to use 'On duplicate key' with 'Insert into Select' statement?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confusion caused by use of alias

```
insert into table1(a, b, c)
select col1 as d, col2 as e, col3 as f from table2
on duplicate key update b = table2.col2, c = table2.col3;
```

Comment: Yes I have tried both... Its not working. And I want to update table 2 data into table1, so value(a) and value(b) will not work.

Comment: Yes..I have tried that as well... Not working. its showing same error

Comment: Nopes, this one works. I am now at a mysql console and I tried it before posting.

Comment: I mean similar error.  Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'table2.col2' in 'field list'

Comment: Hey... actually it was not working because of group by in select query. :-)  on duplicate key update b = t2.col2, c = t2.col3; -- this is working